# C++ Loading A File

Tags: c++, maze, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file with a 12x12 ASCII maze in it. However, all I'm getting on the screen is a 12x12 grid of asterisks.

I used similar code in a CLI minesweeper game I coded last semester and it worked fine. I'm not sure what I've done to cause it to not work...

Code:

```
bool loadBoard(Tile board [][gridSize], string filename) {
    ifstream hndl;
    char isWall;
    hndl.open(filename);

    // Check that the file is opened
    if (hndl.is_open()) {
        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {
                hndl >> isWall;

                if (isWall == '*')
                    board[row][col].wall = true;

                cout << row << col << isWall << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

File maze.txt:

```
************
*   *      *
  * * **** *
 ** *    * *
     *** *  
 * * * * * *
   * * * * *
 * * * * * *
         * *
 ***** *** *
*      *   *
 ***********
```

Output:

```
00* 01* 02* 03* 04* 05* 06* 07* 08* 09* 010* 011*
10* 11* 12* 13* 14* 15* 16* 17* 18* 19* 110* 111*
20* 21* 22* 23* 24* 25* 26* 27* 28* 29* 210* 211*
30* 31* 32* 33* 34* 35* 36* 37* 38* 39* 310* 311*
40* 41* 42* 43* 44* 45* 46* 47* 48* 49* 410* 411*
50* 51* 52* 53* 54* 55* 56* 57* 58* 59* 510* 511*
60* 61* 62* 63* 64* 65* 66* 67* 68* 69* 610* 611*
70* 71* 72* 73* 74* 75* 76* 77* 78* 79* 710* 711*
80* 81* 82* 83* 84* 85* 86* 87* 88* 89* 810* 811*
90* 91* 92* 93* 94* 95* 96* 97* 98* 99* 910* 911*
100* 101* 102* 103* 104* 105* 106* 107* 108* 109* 1010* 1011*
110* 111* 112* 113* 114* 115* 116* 117* 118* 119* 1110* 1111*
```

Comment: What happens if the upper wall is not all asterisks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code "skips" any whitespace. You can do `cin >> noskipws >> isWall;` - or you could use a different character to show "not wall", such as `'.'` or `'-'`.

Comment: Ahh, I figured it had to do with it being whitespace but wasn't sure how to circumvent the issue. I wasn't allowed to change the character used to define an open corridor or a wall. noskipws is a nice simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

`>>` operator ignores whitespace characters, that's why it skips over the blanks and always consumes an asterix. Use `std::istream.get()` instead.